# Why should I use multiple workers?

Tags: mining-pools, miner-configuration

Why should I use multiple workers for different computers? In which case should I create another worker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use multiple workers if you want separate statistics for them, or if the pool you are using limits the number of connections that are allowed per worker.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a worker per machine.

This way, the mining pool will be able to track each system's contribution to the work being done.

Comment: Yeah, but other than that